# How can I pick a range with a modeless dialog in Google Sheets App Scripts with mouse selection?

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a Google Sheet's add-on, for which I require to get the user to select a range using a modeless dialog, which then would be used by some other functions.

I've managed to get [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382359/prompt-user-for-range-in-gs-function-pass-array-to-html-script-and-re-focus-on/45427670#45427670) to work correctly, but don't like the user experience of needing to click on a button to get the range copied to the input box.

Is there any way I can get users to input the range with their mouse, similar to what happens when want to create a chart using pure Google Sheets? Here's [a video](https://vimeo.com/453786706) of the intended functionality.

Thanks!

Comment: [Perhaps onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) could work for you

Comment: But that would run server side, right? How can I keep pushing that information to the client without requesting it from the client with google.script.run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can do it with Web Polling, that is with [setInterval()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

Sample:

*code.gs*

```js
function dialog()//run me
{
  var html=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(html, 'Select a range');
}
```

*index.html*

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <script>
  function onSuccess(range){
    console.log("onSuccess called");
    document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=range;
  }
  function polling(){
  console.log("polling called");
    setInterval( function(){google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).getValues()},500);
   }    
  </script>
  <body onload="polling()">
    <div> Range: </div>
    <div id="range">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```