# ui.prompt to select cell value google script

Tags: google-apps-script, prompt

I want to use a ui.prompt to select a cell value.

I can do that using HTML dialog but that seems like such overkill when all I want is the value of a single cell.

How to use ui.prompt to select a cell value with app script

Comment: I would consider using a modeless dialog and let the user select the cell and push a button to record it into a text box.  In my view it's a lot easier than asking a question on SO.

Comment: I see you wrote this. And it works well. Thanks  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382359/prompt-user-for-range-in-gs-function-pass-array-to-html-script-and-re-focus-on