# There are two onClick events in a modal dialog into one onClick event Google script

Tags: google-apps-script, prompt

I am using modal dialog to select a range from here
[Prompt user for range in .gs function, pass array to html script and re-focus on the HTML dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45382359/prompt-user-for-range-in-gs-function-pass-array-to-html-script-and-re-focus-on)

There are two events in a modal dialog.

The first selects a range, and the second closes the dialog.

```
    <input type="button" id="btn1" value="Range Selected" onClick="selectRange();" />
    <br /><input type="button" id="btn2" value="close" onClick="clearAndClose();"; disabled="true" />
```

How do you combine these into one event so that when the range is selected, the dialog closes without clicking the close button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the selectRange() a server side function:

gs:

```
function saveRange() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range",SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation());
  SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range"));
}


function selectRangeDialog() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("ah2"),"Range Dialog")
}
```

html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>My Html</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Please Select a Range and Press Save</h1>
    <br><input type="button" value="Save" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((v) => google.script.host.close()).saveRange();">
  </body>
</html>
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Here's another way to accomplish the same thing without requiring a separate html file.

```
function saveRange() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty("range", `${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName()}!${SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getA1Notation()}`);
  ss.toast(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty("range"));
}

function launchSaveRangeDialog() {
  const html = '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en"> <head> <base target="_top"> <title>My Html</title> </head> <body> <h1>Please Select a Range and Press Save</h1> <br><input type="button" value="Save" onClick="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler((v) => google.script.host.close()).saveRange();"> </body> </html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Save Dailog");
}
```

Comment: Cooper, when I do this and run the function, the popup shows, but when I click the `Select Range,` nothing happens. The range is not selected, and the modal does not close.

Comment: I thought the point was to have the user select the range and you just wanted to collect their selection and save it for later use

Comment: Cooper, Thank you.

Comment: Why `PropertiesService`? Why not just `toast` directly?